# How to store a scaleable sized extensible event log?

Tags: database, data-structures, file-io

I've been contemplating writing a simple "event log" that takes a paramater list and stores event messages in a log file, trouble is, I forsee this file growing to be rather large (assume 1M entries or more)  the question is, how can I implement this system without pulling teeth, I know that SQL would be a possible way to go.

XML would be ideal but not really practical for scaleability if i'm not going nuts.

Example Log Entry

-----Time Date-------- ---------Sender----------------------- ---------Tags---------- --Message----------

12/24/2008 24:00:00 $DOMAIN\SYSTEM\Application$ :Trivial: :Notification: It's Christmas in 1s

Answer (score 1):

We've had success storing large numbers of events in [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)